# How to render to jframe with lwjgl3?

Tags: java, jframe, lwjgl

I'm trying to render to `jframe` with `lwjgl3`.
The previous `lwjgl2` had a `setParent()` method, but since there is no `Display` class in `lwjgl3`, how can I implement the `setParent()` method with `glfw`?
Thank you!

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Some adjustments made for readability. Still requires some specific pointers from OP, limiting to the code that is relevant.

Comment: @Linas , what Ginger is referring to here is that you have too much code. try to narrow down to exactly which code block has the problem you need help with